Low water pressure throughout house after adding outdoor spigot
Plumber added a hose spigot outside off the kitchen. Afterwards, the pressure for all the sinks and showers was off or low. He came back, ran all taps open at once, and cleared debris from aerators, but pressure is still lower than it was. Next steps? (Besides a new plumber!)

Is the main shutoff valve fully open?

Unless the outside spigot is open, then the pressure should be the same as before.  Clearing debris from the aerators could part of the problem, there are more debris in the pipes.

Thanks for your ideas. I appreciate it. Main shutoff valve is fully open, and have cleared debris from the aerators in all taps in the house. Wasn't a lot, and pressure stil low. I'm wondering if the pressure regulator could be clogged from the debris as well?
